# Accessing and manipulating subscribed observable data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I have a service to retrieve data from my backend. I could see the retrieved data in the browser console with this code  `.do(data =>console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))` ---> Showed any array of my data in JSON format.
In my component I subscribe to the service but I can't figure out how to access the retrieve the data to manipulate it because I need to pass as a parameter to a function.

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//inject services
import { HitoService } from '../hito.service';
import {IHito} from '../form-hito/interfaceHito';
declare var vis: any;
declare var swal: any;
declare var $: any;



@Component({
  selector: 'app-time-line',
  templateUrl: './time-line.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./time-line.component.css'],
  providers: [HitoService]
})
export class TimeLineComponent implements OnInit {
 hito1: IHito[];
  constructor(private _hitoService: HitoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  this._hitoService.getHitos()
        .subscribe(hito1 => this.hito1 = hito1); 
        console.log("hitos de DB:");
console.log(this.hito); 
  this.drawtimeline1_1();
 }
```

The data I saw in the console was this:

```
All: [{"_id":"587817c60de1f905b5811786","descrip":" testeo de creacion de hito ","endDate":"2017-01-26","startDate":"2017-01-08","nameHito":"hito test","__v":0},{"_id":"5878180a0de1f905b5811787","descrip":" testeo de creacion de hito otra vez ","endDate":"2017-01-15","startDate":"2017-01-06","nameHito":"hito test number 2","__v":0},{"_id":"587820820b0a4e05c5678ab7","descrip":" testeo de creacion de hito una vez más ","endDate":"2017-01-15","startDate":"2017-01-06","nameHito":"hito test number 3","__v":0},{"_id":"5878d262639a4d0323bfcd4b","descrip":"lslskkdldjdjh","endDate":"2017-01-01","startDate":"2017-01-01","nameHito":"kkakkakakakkaa","__v":0}]
```

How can I access for example backend_data.descrip of each after subscribing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should make some changes to your code

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._hitoService.getHitos()
        .subscribe(hito1 => {
           this.hito1 = hito1
           console.log(this.hito);<-- if you console you will get output
           this.drawtimeline1_1();<-- you can pass this.hito as parameter if you want
        }); 
  }
```

for accessing descrip of each you can do this

1) if you want to show in html view

```
  <ul *ngIf="hito1"> 
     <li *ngFor="let values of hito1">{{values.descrip}}</li>
   </ul>
```

2) if you want to access in component area, you can use lodash 
    https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#forEach

Answer (score 2):

You have to add curly brackets:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._hitoService.getHitos()
        .subscribe(hito1 => {
           this.hito1 = hito1
           console.log("hitos de DB:"...); // defined!
        }); 
        console.log("hitos de DB:"...); // undefined!
  }
```

The second console.log get's executed before the data is actually received, that's why it seems you have not gotten data, when you in fact probably have.

If you are trying to display data in your view, you might need to use `ngIf` or alternatively the elvis operator, to be able to render your data. This because the calls are asynchronous.

So for example wrap your html with

```
<div *ngIf="hito1">
  <!-- Your data manipulation here -->
</div>
```

EDIT: If you wanna access your attributes, it cam easily be done. Taking as example your json, which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "587817c60de1f905b5811786",
        "descrip": " testeo de creacion de hito ",
        "endDate": "2017-01-26",
        "startDate": "2017-01-08",
        "nameHito": "hito test", "__v": 0
    },
    ......
]
```

The whole array and attributes can be iterated and shown, e.g displaying id and name. The following iterates the whole array with *ngFor and displays the id and description of each object.

```
<div *ngIf="hito1">
  <div *ngFor="let data of hito1">
    <div>{{data._id}}</div>
    <div>{{data._descrip}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ATJ_82 Thank you, the code worked but all I could see is: `hitos de DB:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` Is there any way to make show the data in each array or  retrun an array of the whole data directly in a way that I could iterate throught the array with a foreach to get the datas that interest me. Am new and learning to using Observables.

Comment: Hmmh... I provided you exactly same answer that Amit did, but still you unaccepted mine and accepted his. That is somewhat rude, since usually the one who provides answer first is accepted. Just as a comment and thing for you to think about in the future.

Comment: sorry man, that was my fault. Am new to this web and moreover I wanted to mark both has valid answers then I realised it changed it from yours to his... cheers!

Comment: @ATJ_82 and Olusegun i answer this question because real question was " how can I access descrip of each" and i didn't find ATJ answer complete because there is no mention of *ngFor in his answer thats the reason you were getting DB:[object Object]. So i don't think he provided exactly same answer as mine. after my answer he edited his answer to include *ngfor.i didn't edit mine because i know my answer is complete for your question. i am on SO to help other developers and learn :) your answer should be complete not first or last. anyway no problem :) thank you.

Comment: @AmitSuhag Well, I only added the *ngFor afterwards, before I had a comment  with "data manipulation here", I guess I just assumed that OP knew. My bad there. And exactly just now I understood that OP just wanted to access that one attribute, I understood that it was meant for all attributes. Answers should be comlete, definitely. I'm sorry Amit, you deserve the accepted answer in this case. And about being first, that is just polite to accept the first complete answer, in this case yours were first (I wrongly assumed mine was), so I'm sorry, I hope you can accept and understand my mistake.

Comment: @OlusegunOdumosu, I misunderstood your question a bit. So just go ahead and accept Amit's answer. as the correct one. I thought I had a complete answer, when I did not. So Amit was actually first with the complete answer.

Comment: @AJT_82   i don't know if he gonna accept my answer or not but  I'm really impressed with your message :) your politeness deserve +1 upvote :)  cheers!

Comment: @AmitSuhag Well, glad we could sort it out. It was an honest mistake, and glad that you can accept :) Thanks for upvote, you got one too of course ;) Well now this became chitchat. Will remove this comment soon, before I get flagged for chitchatting :D

Comment: @Amit Suhag and AJT_82..... what a matured way of handling things with respect, Amit Suhag answer accepted. cheers guys!!